# How can I get text without specific tags in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I have some html like

```
html = '''<span class="head">A</span>Explanation <span style="color: red;">1</span><span class="head">B</span>Explanation 2<span class="head">C</span>Explanation <span style="color: red;">3</span>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Now I want to separate this by

```
head = ["A", "B", "C"]
contents = ["Explanation 1", "Explanation 2", "Explanation 3"]
```

I could extract heads by

```
head = [i.get_text() for i in soup.select("span.head")]
```

but couldn't figure out how to extract contents.

Comment: It's possible to do it, but the solution will work only if the sample html in the question really represents the actual html.

Comment: The actual html is '''<td style="width:90%;"><span class="head" id="w107b0601" title="w107b0601">東</span>春方也〾說文曰動...爲<span style="color: red;">人</span>賈執英...有東萊氏<span style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">德紅切</span>十七 <span class="head" id="w107b1001" title="w107b1001">菄</span>東風菜義見上注俗加艹 <span class="head" id="w107b1002" title="w107b1002">鶇</span>鶇鵍鳥名美形出廣雅亦作<span style="color: red;">？</span> </td>''' while what I want to get is heads = ["東", "菄", "鶇"], contents = ["春方也...十七 ", "東風菜義見上注俗加艹 ", "鶇鵍鳥名美形出廣雅亦作？ "] so I believe the sample does represent the actual html, now at least...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, my hanzi is not what it should be, but this is what I get:

```
targets = soup.select('span.head')
heads = []
entries = []
for target in targets:
    entry = []
    heads.append(target.text)
    entry.append(target.next_sibling)
    if target.next_sibling.next_sibling.has_attr('style'):
        entry.append(target.next_sibling.next_sibling.text)
    entries.append(''.join(entry).strip().replace('\n\t',''))
print(heads)
print(entries)
```

Output:

```
['東', '菄', '鶇']
['春方也〾說文曰動...爲人', '東風菜義見上注俗加艹', '鶇鵍鳥名美形出廣雅亦作？']
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `zip()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<span class="head">A</span>Explanation <span style="color: red;">1</span><span class="head">B</span>Explanation <span style="color: red;">2</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

contents = []
for tag1, tag2 in zip(
        soup.select('span.head'), soup.select('span:not(span.head)')):
    contents.append(tag1.next.find_next(text=True) + tag2.text)

print(contents)
```

Output:

```
['Explanation 1', 'Explanation 2']
```

Comment: My bad, whether the explanation text is surrounded by a tag or not is arbitrary.